# CSS, transform - всё ли правильно в коде?

Tags: css

Просьба подсказать, насколько правильно ли написан код ниже, то есть, есть ли грубые ошибки? Просто, в браузере всё вроде работает нормально, но используя этот код в веб-редакторе, он начинает немного глючить именно с последней строкой с transform.

```
.box {
    padding: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
.box:before, .box:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
}
.box:after {
    bottom: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 40px 25px #777;
    height: 50px;
    left: 10%;
    width: 80%;
    transform: perspective(480px) rotateX(60deg);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё правильно. Если Редактор что-то показывает, то, обычно, если навести на ошибку, он развернёт её и подскажет, что ему не нравится. Но код написан верно.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Может не правильно задам вопрос, но можно как-то ещё написать, по-другому, но чтобы всё работало?

Comment: Я сейчас посмотрел у себя в VSCode ваш код. У меня никаких ошибок и предупреждений. Всё чистенько. По-другому даже не знаю как это написать :)